# How to display field revisions?

Tags: entities, nodes

I want to keep field revisions: I want to see who changed a field to which value and when. Currently I can keep node revisions, but in the revisions tab, it only shows title and body changes.

1. How can I also keep field revisions?
2. How can I display revisions preferably like this:

   - User 1 changed Color: red to Color: green
   - User 2 changed Color: green to Color: white

Is the second one achievable by Views?

Answer (score 3):

I came across a similar issue and found your post last week. After a bit of searching around I found this module:

https://drupal.org/project/track_field_changes

It appears to cover what you were looking for in terms of functionality as well as what I was trying to cover. I've since installed the module and set it up, but unfortunately whilst some of it is working for me I can't get a view to display the 'value after' or 'value before' fields (See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/81507/how-to-display-values-in-the-value-after-value-before-fields-track-field).

If you still need this functionality perhaps try out the module - if you have success with it let me know as it's still not quite working fully for me, but that could be down to user-errors perhaps.

All the best

Tom

Answer (score 2):

1. Field revisions, at least in Drupal 6, exist alongside node revisions.
2. At least some of that functionality exists in the [Diff module](http://drupal.org/project/diff).

Comment: Indeed, the Diff module takes care of that.

Answer (score 1):

Using the track_field_changes module, I was able to get the side by side values in a view.  Note , I also have revisions turned on for this node type.